# Scanner to take 1 -3 words

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

So I made this scanner and I wanted it to take 1 to 3 strings. 1 being the minimum number of strings it can take and 3 being the maximum number. So far my output is:

```
You can search 1 - 3 words only : 3
Type a name: word1 
Type a name: word2
Type a name: word3
```

Instead, is there a way I can have these words in multiple arrays, due to the fact that my program will be performing mutliple string searches.

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{

    int nnames;
    String[] stringSearch;

    System.out.print("You can search 1 - 3 words only : ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    nnames = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine().trim());

    stringSearch = new String[nnames];
    for (int i = 0; i < stringSearch.length; i++){
            System.out.print("Type a name: ");
            stringSearch[i] = in.nextLine();

    }
```

Comment: "[I want to] have these words in multiple arrays, due to the fact that my program will be performing mutliple string searches." Sorry, I don't understand this part. Why would you need multiple arrays to perform multiple string searches? Really, it shouldn't matter at all where the strings are stored, if you're just passing them into a `void performSearch(string)` method.

Comment: Do you want to have many arrays in order to avoid locking? If yes, there is no locking in searchin. It's read-only(mainly).

Comment: Could you please tell us what are the strings you need to search and where you will be searching them?
Are you taking those three words and looking for them in multiple texts?

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
        int nnames;
        int ind = 0;
        int maxSearch = 10000;//this is max times we can do searching
        String[][] stringSearch = new String[maxSearch][];

        System.out.print("You can search 1 - 3 words only(else means stop search) : ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        nnames = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine().trim());

        while(nnames>=1 && nnames<=3){
            stringSearch[ind] = new String[nnames];
            for (int i = 0; i < stringSearch.length; i++){
                System.out.print("Type a name: ");
                stringSearch[ind][i] = in.nextLine();
            }
            ind++;
            nnames = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine().trim());
        }
    }
```

Comment: if u dn't want to set maxSearch, u can use ArrayList<String[]> and in the end of input u can convert the ArrayList<String[]> to String[][]